# React useState infinity loop

Tags: reactjs

I would like to learn React and therefore trying to build a logfile parser for myself to parse Apache HTTP Logs in CLF format.

However, trying to do this always causes an infinity loop.

```
import React, { useEffect} from "react";
import logfile from './logfile';
import parse from "clf-parser";
    
function App() {
    const [logContent, setLog] = React.useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(Object.keys(logContent).length === 0){
            fetch(logfile)
            .then(r => r.text())
            .then(text => {
                const data = text.split('\n').map(entry => {
                    return parse(entry);
                });
                return data;
            }).then(
                obj => {
                    console.log(obj);
                    setLog(obj);
                    return;
                }
            );
        }
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <header><h1>Logfile Parser</h1></header>
            <main>{
                logContent.map(entry => {
                    return (<div key={entry.key}>{entry.remote_addr}</div>)
                }
            )}</main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

It's directly related to the `setLog(obj);`, if I don't use it I have only two entries in my console. Why two and not one though? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Is the `console.log` printing the same thing infinitely or is it different things?

Comment: With the setLog(obj) commented in, yes it prints infinity objects to the console. With it commented out, it prints two objects to the console.

Comment: If you log before the `useEffect` is it actually rerendering each time?  You declared your `useEffect` to have no dependencies, so I would have expected it to be called only once on the first render.  (You may have two renders if you're running react in strict mode in development.  This is a known and deliberate behavior).

Comment: As a quick note -needs to double check-, I believe that you checking `logContent` inside the `useEffect` pushed the component to be re-rendered and calling the useEffect again despite you set it to no dependencies. You can safely omit the `if` statement and check if the inf loop is still happening.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I did not get an error, just an infinity loop. However, the answer of (@M.Elghamry) was perfectly correct and solved the problem.

Comment: However, I still do not understand why the `console.log()` is called two times.

Comment: @TimNikischin, in development mode, `React.StrictMode` which is in your `index.jsx` does two pass rendering to catch some types of lurking bugs in your visual tree during development. This is not the case for the production build, it is a development feature only You will get used to this behavior after some time with react. Refer to `Strict Mode` in react docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [M. Elghamry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10699612/m-elghamry) pointed out correct in the comments, the checking for the `logContent` within the `useEffect()` was the problem.

After removing the `if` statement, the loop does not continue happening.

```
import React, { useEffect} from "react";
import logfile from './logfile';
import parse from "clf-parser";
    
function App() {
    const [logContent, setLog] = React.useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(logfile)
        .then(r => r.text())
        .then(text => {
            const data = text.split('\n').map(entry => {
                return parse(entry);
            });
            return data;
        }).then(
            obj => {
                console.log(obj);
                setLog(obj);
                return;
            }
        );
    }, [])
    
    return (
        <div>
            <header><h1>Logfile Parser</h1></header>
            <main>{
                logContent.map(entry => {
                    return (<div key={entry.key}>{entry.remote_addr}</div>)
                }
            )}</main>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Glad my quick note helped!